# Invalid XML Characters accessing URL

Tags: php, xml

I am using a PHP script that reads in an xml file, assigns it to a variable, and then converts it to a PHP array.
When I access the xml's URL using the following code, I get Invalid Character Errors:

```html
<?php
    $handle = fopen($url, "r");

    if($handle){
        while(!feof($handle)){
            $xml = fgets($handle, 4096);

        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
     // OR
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
?>
```

However, if I copy and paste the xml output and assign it to a variable directly in the script, it correctly converts the xml data to a PHP array.

Here's the xml url

```html
<?php
$url = "http://66.42.196.109:5609";
?>
```

I need it to work by pulling the xml directly from the URL.  Any ideas?

Comment: is allow_url_fopen enabled? If not, you're passing your url as a literal string to simplexml, which would be expecting xml, not `http:....`. plus, your while loop is incorrect, you're OVERWRITING `$xml` on every iteration, leaving only the LAST 4k block fetched in the string, which means you'll have partial+corrupted xml

Comment: Marc, I added ini_set("allow_url_fopen", true);  before the simplexml command and still get Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 4: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Comment: so do `var_dump(file_get_contents($url))` and see what you're really receiving.

Comment: If you access url, http://66.42.196.109:5609, directly you will not see <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> at the top of the page, but if you look at the Source Code of the page it is there.  Is that the problem, or is that normal?

Comment: yes, but that's in our browsers. you have to confirm that your php code is receiving the same thing.

Comment: using var_dump(file_get_contents($url)) I get: string(12821) "
Mazak FCA750PY-N26 CONTOUR INDEX CONTOUR SPINDLE INDEX CONTOUR SPINDLE INDEX "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64641/discussion-between-user1344131-and-marc-b).